# ListView Refreshing GetView()

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

In my application I have a ListView with "sections". For each item, I added a letter, but they are visible only for the first word beginning with that letter. It works fine, but if I scroll down in my ListView, the order changes, that means the letter is going to next item.

Example:

```
A
--

 - Alligator
 - Ant
 - Antelope
 - Ape
```

But when I scroll down, the following happens:

```
 - Aligator

A
--
 - Ant
 - Antelope
 - Ape
```

Function that adds the letter I have implemented in GetView()

How can I solve this problem?
I read that ListView is refreshing while scrolling, how can I disable refreshing? Or is there the other way to solve this?

```
protected string old_char = "";
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
                var item = sw_items [position];
                View view;

          convertView = null;

                view = (convertView ??
                    this.context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemLayout,
                  parent,
                  false)) as LinearLayout;

                var txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtTitle);
                txtTitle.SetText (sw_items [position].name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

                var alfabet = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.alfabet);
                var linAlfabet = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.Lin_Alfabet);

          if (convertView == null) {  
            string cnv_char = item.name [0].ToString ().ToUpper ();
            alfabet.Text = cnv_char;
            if (cnv_char != old_char) {
              alfabet.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
              linAlfabet.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            } else {
              alfabet.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
              linAlfabet.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }

            //saving previous char
            old_char = cnv_char;
          }

                return view;


        }

      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add the code you use on your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised**

**First**, the basic scheme for `getView()` implementations is as follows.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    // the system does not want me to recycle a view object, so create a new one
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayyoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, parent, false);
}
// here, set up the convertView object, no matter whether it was recycled or not
...
return convertView;
```

Given the code snippet you posted, all you probably have to do is: 1. remove the `convertVire = null;` statement which Yatin suggested and 2. remove the surrounding `if (convertView == null) {` including closing `}` around the `string cnv_char... old_char = cnv_char` block.  Make sure to set everything properly for `convertView`, because it is not guaranteed to be a fresh object.

**Second**, your code is relying on `getView()` being called in a particular order, which is not the case. Currently, you're relying on `old_char` being set to the starting letter of the last item (in the order in which they appear in the list). This is not guiaranteed.

I suggest you use the `position` argument to access the previous entry of the list (except for the first, of course) and check for a difference, showing the starting letter of the current item if there is no predecessor or if it starts with a different letter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this to my code.

Comment: @lukso Can you maybe describe the problem you face when trying to follow this scheme.

Comment: I'm using C# and what you posted is Java. That's why I can't implement this.

Comment: Alright. Given the code snippet you posted, all you probably have to do is: 1. remove the `convertVire = null;` statement which Yatin suggested and 2. remove the surrounding `if (convertView == null) {` including closing `}` around the `string cnv_char... old_char = cnv_char` block and you should be fine.

Comment: I followed your steps, but now i'm back to the situation before.

Comment: @lukso I'm sorry. You're right. I was jumping on the "it's the View recycling issue" train too fast. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ListView reuses views in stack to replace the view which is scrolled up to place it again at the bottom

try adding the following statement in the  code before as :-

**convertView=null;**

before it checks  for

**if(convertView==null);**

Comment: add it in the getView() method for your customListAdapter.

Comment: It is worth noting that this suggested approach -- ignoring the recycling of views -- is definitely not what Android expects from a `getView()` implementation and it also does not save the app any effort -- how would setting up an existing object be less effective than setting up a freshly created object? Also, your solution will only resolve the problem if the original poster has made a particular implementation mistake, which is not guaranteed. It would have been nice if you had asked him first, and if you had pointed out that your solution is not Android-ish.